# What exactly is the last match of a regular expression with group references (in Python regex)?

Tags: python, regex, reference

`group` is supposed to yield the **last** match of a group of a regular expression, while the Python regex module also provides `captures` to yield **all** matches. When using `group` for a group with a **group reference**, the last match *only of the named group* is returned by `group`, ignoring the matches *of the references* returned by `captures`:

```
>>> import regex
>>> m = regex.fullmatch('(?P<x>.)*(?&x)', 'abc')
>>> m.captures('x')
['a', 'b', 'c']      # all matches, both of x and &x
>>> m.group('x')
'b'                  # last match only of matches of x, ignoring &x
```

Without a reference, just copying the named group, it works as expected:

```
>>> m = regex.fullmatch('(?P<x>.)(?P<x>.)(?P<x>.)', 'abc')
>>> m.captures('x')
['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> m.group('x')
'c'                  # last match of all three matches
```

Does anyone know if this is intended behavior or might be a bug? And if intended, why it is like this? Does the match object provide any information about to which part of the regex a match belongs, to the named group or the reference?

I am using regex 2018.8.29, Python 3.6.5 and opensuse 15.0.

Comment: That looks like a bug. The recursive pattern works like a  "half" capturing group: adds to `captures`, but not to the `group`.

Comment: I filed an issue report with the regex developer and it seems to be not just a bug. If you are interested, see here for more details: https://bitbucket.org/mrabarnett/mrab-regex/issues/296/group-references-are-not-taken-into

Comment: They say it is the same way as in Perl and PCRE, but those do not expose the `captures` stack. So, probably, they are right. Unfortunately, .NET regex does not support recursion, so no way to compare with that engine.